# Mercurial - is there a way to change message on a pushed commit?

Tags: mercurial

I tried `hg commit --amend` it says: 
`abort: cannot amend public changesets`

I don't want to rollback as it's pushed and partly reviewed already

Comment: Are you the only one who can see this repository, or have build servers or other people already pulled your changes?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way other than rewriting the history, with the risk that other people might already haved pulled your changes.

Actually `hg rollback` is for undoing a change that has already been committed but not pushed yet.
While `hg backout` is for performing an inverse operation (but leaving the one you pushed) to come back to the previous state; which is not really what you would like.

I suggest to leave it as is. If you have access to the server, it would be possible to change the repository history but this is not advised.